# Auto-renewable subscription Server Notification

Tags: ios, itunes-app, in-app-subscription

I am developing an apple apps using auto renewable iap subscription. The duration of the subscription is 1 month. For the testing I am using sandbox user. If the testing using the sandbox user, the period for one month will 5 minutes.

I've already setup the subscription url in itunes connect. After I purchase the subscription via my apps, my server got the notification from itunes. But after 5 minutes, my server should get the notification that the subscription is renew, but my server never got that notification from itunes.

How to get continous notification from itunes to my server?

Comment: Have you found out why that happens?

Comment: @m1crdy apparently according to my research and forums, it seems that if you use the sandbox user you can't get all the server notification. But if you using the real user you will get the server notification.